# How many request per seconds can I do with a free gmaps account?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know that the limit for free accounts of gmaps is 2500 requests per day, but is there a limit on how many request/per seconds I can make?

I ask this because I'm having problems if making two requests in a row if I don't put a little pause between each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced a bit with it, and it seems that the limit is not in minutes, but if you do more than 10 requests in a short time (within a second) you will have to wait to do more. Two requests have never been a problem for me. Whenever I have to do a lot I just make sure to make the thread sleep if the google maps status is OVER_REQUEST_LIMIT and then try again :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It appears to be the same [10 requests per second](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits) limit as a default Business account has, according to [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits):

> The Google Geocoding API has the following limits in place:
>
> **Users of the free API:** 2,500 requests per 24 hour period. **10 requests
>   per second.** Maps for Business customers: 100,000 requests per 24 hour
>   period. 10 requests per second. Note: These limits apply to the Google
>   Geocoding web service which is primarily intended for server-side
>   geocoding. If you are geocoding data in response to user input on the
>   web, or on a mobile device, consider using client side geocoding.
>
> These limits are enforced to prevent abuse and/or repurposing of the
>   Geocoding API, and may be changed in the future without notice.
>   Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the
>   service. If you exceed the 24-hour limit or otherwise abuse the
>   service, the Geocoding API may stop working for you temporarily. If
>   you continue to exceed this limit, your access to the Geocoding API
>   may be blocked.
>
> For guidance on strategies for optimizing quota usage, please refer to
>   Usage Limits for Google Maps API Web Services and Geocoding
>   Strategies.
>
> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For
>   complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of
>   Service License Restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, google states:

> Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the
>   service

But it doesn't give any number.